# Java - How to Get a Unique Number from Computer

Tags: java, operating-system, unique, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a unique computer identifier in Java (like disk id or motherboard id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986732/how-to-get-a-unique-computer-identifier-in-java-like-disk-id-or-motherboard-id)
>   [Need to identify local machine somehow in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033938/need-to-identify-local-machine-somehow-in-java)

I want to get some sort of unique ID for the computer (ie IP address).

I have tried:

```
InetAddress inetAddress = null;
try {
    inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
} catch (final UnknownHostException ex) {}
return inetAddress.getHostAddress();
```

This gives an IP, but this one seems to change periodically. Is there a way to get one the DOES NOT change?

Thanks in advance!

NOTE:

I need to be able to associate this ID with the computer.

Comment: What if the user buys a new hard drive?

Comment: Note that local IPs are very non-unique.

Comment: Maybe the MAC address?  Though that could change too if they replaced the network interface.

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Especially on a laptop with WiFi disabled (and sometimes a wired connection)

Comment: do CPUs have something like a vehicle identification number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the machine is on DHCP, the IP address will change periodically. You could use the hostname, or you could use the MAC address, which you can get with [java.net.NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress%28%29)

Comment: Will this address NOT change?

Comment: Yep the MAC address is clearly the best choice here. Ignoring some rare situations (say VMs, someone changing the MAC address) it's guaranteed to be globally unique - what else could you want. Although it still can change - we could swap the network card or install a second one, etc.

Comment: Could I get help with adding code for this? I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: How hard have you tried in 5 minutes? :-)

Comment: It keeps on saying: "non-static method getHardwareAddress() cannot be referenced from a static context." No matter what I do, I can't get it. Happy?

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337: That's an _instance method_.  Note that most users have multiple `NetworkInterface`s, and that WiFi adapters on laptops can be turned off.

Comment: If you know the IP address you want to use, call `NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress()` with it to get hold of a `NetworkInterface`. Then call `getHardwareAddress()` on that.